# How to add dict to yaml?

Tags: python, yaml

I'm using ruamel.yaml for working with yaml. I'm having issues to add dict to yaml file.

My dict looks like this:

```py
data = dict(
    name="string",
    packet=dict(
        frame_number=num,
```

I'm changing the values (num) in dict in for loop like this:

```py
for packet in packets:
   output_yaml(packet, num)
```

I would like to achieve that when calling *output_yaml* it adds an entry in output.yaml.

My yaml:

```py
with open("output.yaml", "w") as file:
   yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
   yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
   yaml.compact(seq_seq=False, seq_map=False)
   yaml.dump(data, file)
```

For loop just rewrites the data added in yaml.
I want yaml file to look like this:

```
name: "string"
packet: 
   frame_number: 1

name: "string"
packet: 
   frame_number: 2

name: "string"
packet: 
   frame_number: 3
```

How do I achieve this? Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Open the file in `a` mode to append.

Comment: Your YAML is invalid. You can't have duplicate keys (`name`, `packet`) in the same mapping. Be aware that a YAML implementation may refuse to read in this file.